# Is there a differentiable $f$ st $f' \ne 0$ st for $a\not \in \mathbb{Q}, \ f(a) \in \mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, examples-counterexamples

There are many easy examples for differentiable $f$ st $f'(x) \ne 0$ and for $a \in \mathbb{Q}, \  f(a) \not \in \mathbb{Q}$ for example $\pi x , e^x,$  etc, but the question is: Is the converse true ? i.e Is there a differentiable $f$ st $f'\ne 0$ on $\mathbb{R}$ st  for $a\not \in \mathbb{Q}, \  f(a) \in \mathbb{Q}$?

Of course $f$ couldn't be 1-1 function but can this $f$ exist ? I was not able to find any example.

I think the answer is to this question is such function couldn't exist because the cardinality of irrationals is bigger than rations but I couldn't prove that.

Comment: $f\equiv0$. But I'm not sure if there is for non constant functions

Comment: @AngaeMT I forgot to put the condition $f' \ne 0$ for some reason

Comment: Every continuous function with this property is constant. If you do not like $f\equiv 0$, you can take $f\equiv 1$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I couldn't prove that, can you give a proof ?

Comment: I guess if it is not constant, then range of $f$ is interval. Then you can pick a rational $q$ such that $f(q)$ is irrational. Then construct an irrational sequence to $q$ to derive contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Claim. If $f: \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is continuous and sends every irrational number to a rational number, then $f$ is constant.

Proof. Suppose not. Then there exist $x\ne y$ such that $a=f(x)\ne b=f(y)$. After relabelling, we can assue that  $a<b$. The interval $[a,b]$ has cardinality of continuum. Since $\mathbb Q$ is countable, so is $f(\mathbb Q)$. Thus, $f(\mathbb Q)\cup f(\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q)$ is countable (since $f(\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q)\subset \mathbb Q$). Hence,  $f(\mathbb R)$ cannot contain $[a,b]$. Thus, there exists $c\in [a,b]$ such that $c\notin f(\mathbb R)$. This contradicts the intermediate value theorem. qed